# Javascript function in loop

Tags: javascript

I need to show on page many hidden blocks, that are displayed by functions:

```
function show() {
    document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'block';
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'none';
}

function show_x() {
    document.getElementById('info_x').style.display = 'block';
}

function hide_x() {
    document.getElementById('info_x').style.display = 'none';
}
```

How to hide all those functions in one loop?
Why my loop doesn't work?

```
function show() {
    document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'block';
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'none';
}

for (var i = 1; i++; i <= 50) {

    function show + i + () {
        document.getElementById('info' + i + '').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hide + i + () {
        document.getElementById('info' + i + '').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write like this:

```
function show+i+()
```

You should pass `i` as parameter into your function `show` or `hide`:

```
function show(idAppend) {
    document.getElementById('info' + idAppend).style.display='block';
}

for (var i=1; i++; i<=50){
    show(i);
}
```

This will show all blocks with id `infoX`, where `X` is the number from 1 to 50.

### How to call function by its name

If you want to call function by its name from variable, your should use this syntax (depending on the context):

```
window[functionName](arguments)
```

For example, let's call function with the name `show5` with the single parameter `message`:

```
function show5(message){
    alert(message);
}

// store name of the function in variable
var functionName = 'show5';

// call function with parameter "Hello!" by its name
window[functionName]('Hello!')
```